# How to copy paste the azure logical app action blocks?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a workflow which sends a mail to different groups based on group Name. I am using switch case for this purpose. Here I wanted to copy the outlook action block to all the cases as only 'To Address' will change.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to set a variable with the 'To' address in your switch cases. 
That way you only need one mail action shape.

That being said, you can copy/paste using the code view.

Answer (score 0):

copy/paste from json wouldn't work since there will be depencies in the values. afaik it would need to be a backend code feature in the logic app editor. I've asked for the same feature.